# Body tabIndex="-1"

Tags: html, dom, focus, tabindex

I use chromium. Navigation in the application by pressing the tab key returns the elements tabindex = "0". Other elements skip tabindex = "- 1". But  does not skip. What is the reason for this?

Comment: The `-1` is an invalid value though it work on some browsers. For the ones you want to skip, give them a higher value than the amount of elements you use, and they will end up at the bottom of the tab list

Comment: This did not solve my problem. The <body tabindex = -1> or <body tabindex = 10000> tag is focused.

Comment: Since the tabindex is for form elements, such as input, you have to add a minimal working code sample reproducing the issue, and an explanation of what you want to happen (or not happen)

Comment: HTML5 defined user interaction for tabindex: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

Comment: You have a space between the `-` and the `1` in `"- 1"` and `isNaN("- 1") == true` i.e. the string can't be coerced into a number. I used `element.setAttribute('tabindex', "- 1")` and then reading back the value that the DOM ends up using by reading `element.tabIndex`, and in Chrome that showed the tabIndex stays as its default value (-1 or 0 depending on element type).